# ggplot multiple plots selecting own colors

Tags: r, ggplot2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change line and shape colours in ggplot2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835451/how-to-change-line-and-shape-colours-in-ggplot2)

```
pdf('test',onefile=T)
    g <- ggplot(test,aes(x=timepoints,y= mean,ymax = mean + sde, ymin = mean  - sde,colour=Experiment)) + 
       geom_errorbar(width=2) + 
       geom_point() +
       geom_line() +
       xlab('Time (min)') +
       ylab('Fold Induction') +          
       opts(title = '5 min v 6 hr KCl treatment')    
    print(g)
dev.off()
```

this is what it prints.

[image]

how do I change the colour from the default to let's say red and black? so '5 min' is red and '6 hr' is black?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/11835451/1317221

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use scale_manual to manually define the scales:

```
g + scale_colour_manual(values = c("red", "black"))
```

Comment: this is the best thing to happen since sliced bread

Comment: if my colour = two words within ggplot(...) is there a way to correct for that

Comment: it doesn't like it, the two words are a column